# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory

Tags: websphere

I have installed my application and restarted in `WAS 8.5`, I see below exception in `SystemOut.log`,where as it works fine in `WAS 7`.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/security/KeyStore;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/security/KeyStore;Ljava/security/SecureRandom;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/X509HostnameVerifier;)V
```

Can any one help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You need to supply more information, for example -What kind of app is it (WEB App, EJB App, etc). Also, can you cut and post more detail from the SystemOut.log file, assuming there is any.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you're deploying and trying to use one version of Apache HttpClient, but that WebSphere has a different version included in its libraries. If you could use the WebSphere-included version, that would be simplest, but if you need to use the specific version, you could change the WebSphere classloader policy to PARENT_LAST.

Answer (score -1):

websphere8  /WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar has packages org.http.*
com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar and HttpClient.jar conflict!

Change classloaders order invalid because com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar has been loaded when websphere start!

you can change HttpClient packages from org.http.* to net.test.* to avoid conflict

ps:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/websphere/library/techarticles/1108_jiangwk_classloader/1108_jiangwk_classloader.html